# Is it possible to query and sync only a part of CloudKit's Public database with local Core Data storage

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Reading an [article](https://fatbobman.medium.com/core-data-with-cloudkit-part-5-synchronizing-public-database-a7354d716ffc) on Public CloudKit databases I've come across this:

> Core Data with CloudKit synchronizes the public database by saving a local mirror of the **entire** public database.

If I add new content to my Public CloudKit DB every day, and I want new users to download only the last 10 days of content when they open my app for the first time. And be able to "Download more" later (like pagination). Can I do that? Or each user would be forced to download hundreds (thousands) of previous CloudKit Records?